# Need some advice with PHP loop

Tags: php, html, database, loops

I need to make a loop that get data from the db...and print the data in `<li>` BUT every 5 `li` need to be in a `ul`...

how can I do this loop?

Comment: You could use `array_chunk()` to split your array in arrays with 5 elements in it and then loop through each of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with `NoRewindIterator` and with `LimitIterator`. Just wrap the Iterator you get back from your database client library that represents the resultset into the `NoRewindIterator` and you then can do the 5 iterations each with the `LimitIterator` until the overall iterator is invalid:

```
$it = new NoRewindIterator($result);

$it->getInnerIterator()->rewind(); # Rewind once

while ($it->valid())
{
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach (new LimitIterator($it, 0, 5) as $row)
    {
        echo '<li>', .... , '</li>' ;
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

*Edit:* Added the `rewind()` operation because it is needed by default for some iterators that do not automatically rewind, for all the details see a reference question I've created: [*When does the NoRewindIterator rewind the inner Iterator?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16682198/367456)

Comment: +1 Here's the kind of answer I expect to a trivial question like this one.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the `modulo` operator?

```
$counter = 0;

echo '<ul>';

while ($row = fetchRow())
{
    $counter++;

    if ($counter % 5 == 0) echo '</ul><ul>';

    echo '<li>' . $row['field'] . '</li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another counter:

```
$counter=0;
echo '<ul>';
while($record_in_database=fetch_it_somehow){
  if($counter==5){
    $counter=0;
    echo '</ul><ul>'; // *
    }
  echo '<li>'.$record_in_database->retrieve_data_somehow().'</li>';
  ++$counter;
} // end while
echo '</ul>'; // you must close it as you've opened in * marked line
```