# When does the NoRewindIterator rewind the inner Iterator?

Tags: php, iterator, spl

By its name it is perfectly clear when PHP's `NoRewindIterator` rewinds: never.

But sometimes, esp. when extending from it, I ask myself: Does it ever rewind? Does it rewind once? So if I need it, do I need to implement the (first) rewind as some *`Traversable`* might require it?

I specifically wonder about the inner iterator here, so the [`Iterator`](http://php.net/Iterator) the `NoRewindIterator` class takes as parameter with its constructor.

For example:

```
$iterator = new SomeIterator(); // implements Iterator
$noRewind = new NoRewindIterator($iterator);
foreach ($noRewind as $value) {
    break;
}
```

Will `$iterator->rewind()` be never called when using `$noRewind` from here on? Or will it be called once for the first time `$noRewind->rewind()` is invoked (e.g. within the first `foreach` in the example). Or maybe on construct?

Answer (score 1):

Like by the name of the class alone (`NoRewindIterator`), [the manual has](http://php.net/NoRewindIterator) the following wording in specific:

> NoRewindIterator  - This iterator cannot be rewound.

And for the concrete method:

> NoRewindIterator::rewind() - Prevents the rewind operation on the inner iterator.

This implies that the `Iterator::rewind()` method is not passed through to the inner iterator. Tests also show this, here is a simple one I've been running (code of all iterators not part of PHP are in the [Iterator Garden](https://github.com/hakre/Iterator-Garden)):

```
$iterator = new RangeIterator(1, 1);
$debug    = new DebugIteratorDecorator($iterator);
$noRewind = new NoRewindIterator($debug);

echo "first foreach:\n";

foreach ($noRewind as $value) {
    echo "iteration value: $value\n";
}
```

In this code, the debug-iterator prints (echoes) iteration information on the fly:

```
first foreach:
Iterating (RangeIterator): #0 valid()
Iterating (RangeIterator): #0 parent::valid() is TRUE
Iterating (RangeIterator): #0 current()
Iterating (RangeIterator): #0 parent::current() is 1
iteration value: 1
Iterating (RangeIterator): #1 next()
Iterating (RangeIterator): #1 after parent::next()
Iterating (RangeIterator): #1 valid()
Iterating (RangeIterator): #1 parent::valid() is FALSE
```

As this shows, `$iterator->rewind()` is never called.

This also makes sense for the same reasons given in a related question: [*Why must I rewind IteratorIterator*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2458955/367456). The `NoRewindIterator` extends from `IteratorIterator` and *different* to it's parent class, the `getInnerIterator()` method returns an `Iterator` and not a `Traversable`.

This change allows you to initialize the rewind when you need to:

```
echo "\n\$calling noRewind->getInnerIterator()->rewind():\n";

$noRewind->getInnerIterator()->rewind();

echo "\nsecond foreach:\n";

foreach ($noRewind as $value) {
    echo "iteration value: $value\n";
}
```

Exemplary debug output again:

```
$calling noRewind->getInnerIterator()->rewind():
Iterating (RangeIterator): #0 rewind()
Iterating (RangeIterator): #0 after parent::rewind()

second foreach:
Iterating (RangeIterator): #0 valid()
Iterating (RangeIterator): #0 parent::valid() is TRUE
Iterating (RangeIterator): #0 current()
Iterating (RangeIterator): #0 parent::current() is 1
iteration value: 1
Iterating (RangeIterator): #1 next()
Iterating (RangeIterator): #1 after parent::next()
Iterating (RangeIterator): #1 valid()
Iterating (RangeIterator): #1 parent::valid() is FALSE
```

Knowing about these details then does allow to create a `OneTimeRewindIterator` for example:

```
/**
 * Class OneTimeRewindIterator
 */
class OneTimeRewindIterator extends NoRewindIterator
{
    private $didRewind = FALSE;

    public function rewind() {
        if ($this->didRewind) return;

        $this->didRewind = TRUE;
        $this->getInnerIterator()->rewind();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is also this: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#making-collections-rewindable

Answer (score 0):

`NoRewindIterator` can sort of rewind in some cases.

E.g. when you use continue to a cycle outside:

```
<?php
$iterator = new NoRewindIterator(new ArrayIterator([1, 2, 3, 4]));
foreach ([1, 2, 3, 4] as $a) {
    foreach ($iterator as $b) {
        echo "$a\t$b\n";
        continue 2;
    }
}
```

One could expect it to print ones be ones, twos by twos, and so on, but actually this code prints:

```
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
```

Swapping `continue 2` with a plain `break` does not change a thing.

```
<?php
$iterator = new \NoRewindIterator(new \ArrayIterator([1, 2, 3, 4]));

$array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

foreach ($array as $a) {
    foreach ($iterator as $b) {
        echo "$a\t$b\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

If you wrap this iterator with a debugging iterator you would see that `next()` never gets called if you break the loop by any means. Therefore you would always receive the first values. Yet it would seem like the iterator got rewinded somehow.