# What's the best way to compare / insert / update products in a MySQL db from a .CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv, datamapper

At our company we pull a .CSV file from the suppliers FTP server and update our product data (price, stock,..) each morning.

We wrote a cron for this task as it should run automatically.

The current script is working in most cases. However, sometimes we recieve an error: 'Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 75 bytes)'.

We use CodeIgniter with DataMapper ORM. A possible design error might be the fact that the script is working with objects instead of array's...

Each time 49000 rows are checked.

Can anyone help us find another way of doing this?

---

The following script is the function that runs after the files are copied.

```
// Include auth connection params
$udb = $this->_completeParams($db);
// Check if an update was downloaded
$supplier = new Supplier(NULL,$udb);
$supplier->where(array('alias'=>'XX','name'=>'xxxxxxxxx'))->get(1);

$cronStart = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$cronStartDate = date('Y-m-d');
//mail($this->adminMail, 'CRON', 'Gestart:' .$cronStart, $this->headerMail);

//$message .= '1: '.memory_get_usage()."\r\n";
if($supplier->import_found) {
//if(true) {
    $rows = 0;
    $updated = 0;
    $new = 0;

    //$aAvailable = array();

    $message .= '<h3>Start: '.$cronStart.'</h3>' . "\r\n";

    $object = new Supplier_product(NULL,$udb);
    $cat = new Supplier_category(NULL, $udb);
    $manu = new Supplier_manufacturer(NULL, $udb);

    $auvibel = new Supplier_auvibel(NULL, $udb);
    $bebat = new Supplier_bebat(NULL, $udb);
    $recupel = new Supplier_recupel(NULL, $udb);
    $reprobel = new Supplier_reprobel(NULL, $udb);

    $files = glob($this->tempDir.'XXXXX/prices/*');
    foreach($files as $file) {

        $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $data = ($ext == 'txt')?$this->_csvToArray($file, ';'):false;

        // If the CSV data is in $data
        if($data !== false) {
            $totalCount = count($data);
            for($i = 0; $i <= $totalCount; $i++) {

                //$aAvailable[] = $data[$i]['ArtID'];
                $rows++;
                //$message .= 'loop start: '.memory_get_usage()."\r\n";

                $object->where(array('art_id'=>$data[$i]['ArtID'],'supplier_id'=>$supplier->id))->get(1);

                $auvibel->select('value')->where(array('art_id'=>$data[$i]['ArtID'], 'supplier_id'=>$supplier->id))->get(1);
                $auvibel->value = ($auvibel->exists())?$auvibel->value:0;

                $bebat->select('value')->where(array('art_id'=>$data[$i]['ArtID'], 'supplier_id'=>$supplier->id))->get(1);
                $bebat->value = ($bebat->exists())?$bebat->value:0;

                $recupel->select('value')->where(array('art_id'=>$data[$i]['ArtID'], 'supplier_id'=>$supplier->id))->get(1);
                $recupel->value = ($recupel->exists())?$recupel->value:0;

                $reprobel->select('value')->where(array('art_id'=>$data[$i]['ArtID'], 'supplier_id'=>$supplier->id))->get(1);
                $reprobel->value = ($reprobel->exists())?$reprobel->value:0;

                $intrastat = 0;

                $data[$i]['LP_Eur'] = ($data[$i]['LP_Eur'] != '')?str_replace(',', '.', $data[$i]['LP_Eur']):0;
                $data[$i]['DE_Eur'] = ($data[$i]['DE_Eur'] != '')?str_replace(',', '.', $data[$i]['DE_Eur']):0;
                $data[$i]['D1_Eur'] = ($data[$i]['D1_Eur'] != '')?str_replace(',', '.', $data[$i]['D1_Eur']):0;
                $data[$i]['D1_Eur'] = ($data[$i]['D2_Eur'] != '')?str_replace(',', '.', $data[$i]['D2_Eur']):0;
                $data[$i]['PricePersonal_Eur'] = ($data[$i]['PricePersonal_Eur'] != '')?str_replace(',', '.', $data[$i]['PricePersonal_Eur']):0;
                $data[$i]['BackorderDate'] = ($data[$i]['BackorderDate'] != '')?date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data[$i]['BackorderDate'])):NULL;
                $data[$i]['ModifDate'] = ($data[$i]['ModifDate'] != '')?date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data[$i]['ModifDate'])):NULL;

                if($object->exists()) {
                    if($object->allow_cron_update) { //if($data[$i]['ModifDate'] != $object->modified) {

                        // Check if category group exists
                        $cat->select('id')->where(array(
                            'supplier_id' => $supplier->id,
                            'name_a' => $data[$i]['Class1'],
                            'name_b' => $data[$i]['Class2'],
                            'name_c' => $data[$i]['Class3'],
                        ))->get(1);
                        if(!$cat->exists()) {

                            // Category should be added
                            $cat->supplier_id = $supplier->id;
                            $cat->name_a = $data[$i]['Class1'];
                            $cat->name_b = $data[$i]['Class2'];
                            $cat->name_c = $data[$i]['Class3'];
                            $cat->save();

                            // Log as notification: New supplier categorie
                            $this->_notify('Niewe categorie',array(
                                'body' => $supplier->name.' heeft "'.$cat->name_a.' - '.$cat->name_b.' - '.$cat->name_c.'" als nieuwe categorie toegevoegd.',
                                'controller' => 'leveranciers',
                                'trigger' => 'new_supplier_category',
                                'url' => base_url().'leveranciers/item/'.$supplier->id.'/categorien',
                                'icon' => 'icon-truck',
                                'udb' => $udb,
                            ));
                        }

                        // Check if manufacturer exists
                        $manu->select('id')->where(array(
                            'name' => $data[$i]['PublisherName']
                        ))->get(1);
                        if(!$manu->exists()) {

                            // Manufacturer should be added
                            $manu->name = $data[$i]['PublisherName'];
                            $manu->save($supplier);
                        }

                        // Add the product to the database
                        $object->art_id = $data[$i]['ArtID'];
                        $object->supplier_id = $supplier->id;
                        $object->supplier_category_id = $cat->id;
                        $object->supplier_manufacturer_id = $manu->id;
                        $object->part_id = $data[$i]['PartID'];
                        $object->ean_code = $data[$i]['EanCode'];
                        $object->name = $data[$i]['Description'];
                        $object->description = NULL;
                        $object->version = $data[$i]['Version'];
                        $object->language = $data[$i]['Language'];
                        $object->media = $data[$i]['Media'];
                        $object->trend = $data[$i]['Trend'];
                        $object->price_group = $data[$i]['PriceGroup'];
                        $object->price_code = $data[$i]['PriceCode'];
                        $object->eur_lp = $data[$i]['LP_Eur'];
                        $object->eur_de = $data[$i]['DE_Eur'];
                        $object->eur_d1 = $data[$i]['D1_Eur'];
                        $object->eur_d2 = $data[$i]['D2_Eur'];
                        $object->eur_personal = $data[$i]['PricePersonal_Eur'];
                        $object->stock = $data[$i]['Stock'];
                        $object->backorder = ($data[$i]['BackorderDate'] != '' && !empty($data[$i]['BackorderDate']))?$data[$i]['BackorderDate']:NULL;
                        $object->modified = ($data[$i]['ModifDate'] != '' && !empty($data[$i]['ModifDate']))?$data[$i]['ModifDate']:NULL;
                        $object->flag = 'MODIFIED';
                        $object->auvibel = $auvibel->value;
                        $object->bebat = $bebat->value;
                        $object->intrastat = $intrastat;
                        $object->recupel = $recupel->value;
                        $object->reprobel = $reprobel->value;
                        $object->save();

                        $updated++;
                    }
                    elseif(($object->auvibel != $auvibel) || ($object->bebat != $bebat) || ($object->recupel != $recupel) || ($object->reprobel != $reprobel)) {
                        $object->auvibel = $auvibel->value;
                        $object->bebat = $bebat->value;
                        $object->intrastat = $intrastat;
                        $object->recupel = $recupel->value;
                        $object->reprobel = $reprobel->value;
                        $object->save();
                    }
                }
                else {

                    // Check if category group exists
                    $cat->select('id')->where(array(
                        'supplier_id' => $supplier->id,
                        'name_a' => $data[$i]['Class1'],
                        'name_b' => $data[$i]['Class2'],
                        'name_c' => $data[$i]['Class3'],
                    ))->get(1);
                    if(!$cat->exists()) {

                        // Category should be added
                        $cat->supplier_id = $supplier->id;
                        $cat->name_a = $data[$i]['Class1'];
                        $cat->name_b = $data[$i]['Class2'];
                        $cat->name_c = $data[$i]['Class3'];
                        $cat->save();

                        // Log as notification: New supplier categorie
                        $this->_notify('Niewe categorie',array(
                            'body' => $supplier->name.' heeft "'.$cat->name_a.' - '.$cat->name_b.' - '.$cat->name_c.'" als nieuwe categorie toegevoegd.',
                            'controller' => 'leveranciers',
                            'trigger' => 'new_supplier_category',
                            'url' => '[hidden-url]'.$supplier->id.'/categorien',
                            'icon' => 'icon-truck',
                            'udb' => $udb,
                        ));
                    }

                    // Check if manufacturer exists
                    $manu->select('id')->where(array(
                        'name' => $data[$i]['PublisherName']
                    ))->get(1);
                    if(!$manu->exists()) {

                        // Manufacturer should be added
                        $manu->name = $data[$i]['PublisherName'];
                        $manu->save($supplier);
                    }

                    // Add the product to the database
                    $object->art_id = $data[$i]['ArtID'];
                    $object->supplier_id = $supplier->id;
                    $object->supplier_category_id = $cat->id;
                    $object->supplier_manufacturer_id = $manu->id;
                    $object->part_id = $data[$i]['PartID'];
                    $object->ean_code = $data[$i]['EanCode'];
                    $object->name = $data[$i]['Description'];
                    $object->description = NULL;
                    $object->version = (($data[$i]['Version'] != '')?$data[$i]['Version']:NULL);
                    $object->language = (($data[$i]['Language'] != '')?$data[$i]['Language']:NULL);
                    $object->media = (($data[$i]['Media'] != '')?$data[$i]['Media']:NULL);
                    $object->trend = (($data[$i]['Trend'] != '')?$data[$i]['Trend']:NULL);
                    $object->price_group = (($data[$i]['PriceGroup'] != '')?$data[$i]['PriceGroup']:NULL);
                    $object->price_code = (($data[$i]['PriceCode'] != '')?$data[$i]['PriceCode']:NULL);
                    $object->eur_lp = (($data[$i]['LP_Eur'] != '')?$data[$i]['LP_Eur']:NULL);
                    $object->eur_de = (($data[$i]['DE_Eur'] != '')?$data[$i]['DE_Eur']:NULL);
                    $object->eur_d1 = (($data[$i]['D1_Eur'] != '')?$data[$i]['D1_Eur']:NULL);
                    $object->eur_d2 = (($data[$i]['D2_Eur'] != '')?$data[$i]['D2_Eur']:NULL);
                    $object->eur_personal = $data[$i]['PricePersonal_Eur'];
                    $object->stock = $data[$i]['Stock'];
                    $object->backorder = ($data[$i]['BackorderDate'] != '' && !empty($data[$i]['BackorderDate']))?$data[$i]['BackorderDate']:NULL;
                    $object->modified = ($data[$i]['ModifDate'] != '' && !empty($data[$i]['ModifDate']))?$data[$i]['ModifDate']:NULL;
                    $object->flag = NULL;
                    $object->auvibel = $auvibel->value;
                    $object->bebat = $bebat->value;
                    $object->intrastat = $intrastat;
                    $object->recupel = $recupel->value;
                    $object->reprobel = $reprobel->value;
                    $object->save();
                    //$object->clear_cache();

                    $new++;
                }

                //$message .= 'loop end A: '.memory_get_usage().' - '.$i."\r\n";

                $object->clear();
                $cat->clear();
                $manu->clear();
                $auvibel->clear();
                $bebat->clear();
                $recupel->clear();
                $reprobel->clear();

                unset($data[$i]);

                //$message .= 'loop end B: '.memory_get_usage()."\r\n";
            }
        }
        unset($manu);
        unset($auvibel);
        unset($bebat);
        unset($recupel);
        unset($reprobel);

        if(is_file($file)) {
            unlink($file);
        }

        $object->clear();
        //$message .= 'BEFORE MARK EOL: '.memory_get_usage()."\r\n";
        /**
         * Mark products as EOL when not found in file
         */
        $eolCount = 0;
        $eol = $object
            ->group_start()
                ->where('flag IS NULL')
                ->or_where('flag !=', 'EOL')
            ->group_end()
            ->where('supplier_id', $supplier->id)
            ->group_start()
                ->group_start()->where('updated IS NOT NULL')->where('updated <',$cronStart)->group_end()
                ->or_group_start()->where('updated IS NULL')->where('created <',$cronStart)->group_end()
            ->group_end()
            ->get_iterated();

        $p = new Product(NULL,$udb);
        //unset($aAvailable);
        foreach($eol as $i => $product) {
            $product->flag = "EOL";
            $product->save();

            if($product->art_id != NULL) {
                // The 'copied' products should be marked eol in the webshop!
                $p->where('art_code',$product->art_id)->where('supplier_product_id', $product->id)->get();
                if($p->exists()) {
                    $p->eol = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    $p->save();
                }
                $p->clear();
            }

            $product->clear();
            $eolCount++;
            //unset($eol[$i]);
            //$message .= 'INSIDE MARK EOL: '.memory_get_usage()."\r\n";
        }
        unset($product);
        $object->clear();
        //$message .= 'AFTER MARK EOL: '.memory_get_usage()."\r\n";
        if($eolCount > 0) {
            // Log as notification: supplier products marked EOL
            $this->_notify('EOL melding',array(
                'body' => "Er ".(($eolCount == 1)?'is een product':'zijn '.$eolCount.' producten')." gemarkeerd als EOL",
                'controller' => 'leveranciers',
                'trigger' => 'eol_supplier_product',
                'url' => '[hidden-url]'.$supplier->id.'/artikels',
                'icon' => 'icon-truck',
                'udb' => $udb,
            ));
        }
    }

    // After looping files build e-mail.
    $message .= 'Totaal: '.$rows. "\r\n";
    $message .= 'new: '.$new. "\r\n";
    $message .= 'updated: '.$updated. "\r\n";
    $message .= 'EOL: '.$eolCount. "\r\n";
    $subject = 'Import XXXXX Update';
}
// No updates found
else {
    $subject = 'Import XXXXX No Update Found';
    $message .= "\r\n";
}
$message .= '<h3>Einde: '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'</h3>' . "\r\n";
mail($this->adminMail, $subject, $message, $this->headerMail);

// Remove import_found marker for supplier
$supplier->import_found = false;
$supplier->save();
```

Comment: we're not going to read through a wall of code to guess at the problem, but obviously you're running out of memory. Reduce the amount of "stuff" you're doing in script, or raise PHP's memory limits. Those are your only two options.

Comment: You could use mysqls `LOAD DATA INFILE` in a tmp table. Then add a trigger on the tmp table and insert it into the real table, when validation is succesful. That would massivly improve your import it would take about 1 second.

Comment: I recommend you to chunk your csv file into smaller files in order to avoid the memory exhausted error.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732590/split-large-excel-csv-file-to-multiple-files-on-php-or-javascript

Comment: @MarcB If you think this is a wall of code you really should have a look at the complete controller file. I pasted all relevant code because otherwise people would've been asking me to post code I have up till now.

Comment: @Daan thanks for the sugestion. Allthough the names of the fields in te table of our CRM are different from those comming from the file. I'm not a big fan writing complex SQL triggers or stored procedures.

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar situation. After a lot of attempts at making the script better, we decided that we needed another approach to make our import work and not take ~10 hours.

What we did was dump all the PHP code, and instead use `mysqlimport` to load the contents of the CSV file directly into a table. That table now contains everything we need, but not in a form that's useful for us (no structure, some fields need some processing, etc.)

However, because everything is now in the database, we can do everything we want with a query.
For example, deleting all data that is no longer in the import file, thats just `DELETE FROM structured_table AS st LEFT JOIN unstructured_table AS ut ON st.someField = ut.someField WHERE ut.someField IS NULL;`, updating existing records is just `UPDATE structured_table AS st INNER JOIN unstructured_table AS ut ON st.someField = ut.someField SET st.anotherField = CONCAT(ut.aField, ' ', ut.yetAnotherField);`.

Obviously, for a complex import script, your queries will be more complex and you'll need more of them. You might even need to throw some stored procedures in to do processing on individual fields. But if you can take this kind of approach you'll end up with a process that can handle a lot of data and is very scalable.

Comment: I gave this idea a try (used LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE from in php) and the file is imported in less then 20 sec now. But all other processing (like categorie names in our system are in a different table) might be the bigger problem.

Comment: For the categories, you'd need two queries: One to insert missing records, and one to update your products to set 'supplier_category_id' based on 'supplier_id'. (And maybe one to update categories?) Something like this would do: `INSERT INTO categories (supplier_id, class_a, class_b, class_c) (SELECT id, Class1, Class2, Class3 FROM import_table AS i WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM categories AS c WHERE it.id = c.supplier_id))` for the new records, plus `UPDATE products AS p INNER JOIN categories AS c USING(supplier_id) SET p.supplier_category_id = c.id)` to link products to their categories.

Comment: I really should've payed more attention during SQL class :) Not that I don't understand, but I don't like the readability of queries :p
I'll give it a try.

Comment: However, I think this will get to complex. The supplier provides separate files for Recupel fees etc, these should be added to the price of the product. I might go with Ken Cheungs solution after all..

Comment: The best solution is whatever works for you within your organisation. If you're uncomfortable with SQL, using a very SQL heavy solution can become a maintenance issue. Remember though, you could also opt for a hybrid solution: do the basic grunt work in a few queries and the really complex stuff in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation... Compare around 20M records every day to update a few records with changes and add / remove the delta. Data source is CSV as well. I use perl, while I think php also work.

1. Each record must have a linking key, SKU of product? Or something like that. May already be the primary key /unique key in your DB table.
2. You know the lst of fields that you want to compare and update.

Step 1: read ALL records from DB, store in an array using the linking key as named index.

1.1: value is concat of all fields need to compare, or md5() of the concat result to save memory.

Step 2: loop through the CSV file, extract the linking key and new values per row.

2.1: if linking key is NOT in the array, INSERT action to DB.

2.2: isset() return true so compare the values (or md5() of the value concat), if different, UPDATE action to DB.

2.3: delete this entry from the array.

Step 3: by the end of reading the CSV, the entries remains in the array were records to DELETE.

In my case, it use less than 2GB RAM for the process and runs around 3 minutes, which should be feasible and acceptable.

Comment: PS: One other concern for me is that I cannot allow the database table / records being lock up by query with long processing time. 20M records join 20M records......

Comment: We had indeed some troubles in the past with locking tables / records, We changed to innoDB to get around it.
This solution kinda suits our needs. For the concat value, do you mean like: name;ean;art;...;...
Isn't it 'heavy' for php to compare strings that size?

Comment: If you use innoDB, be aware that all changes just grow the size of the ibdata1 file, include DELETE, and you cannot reclaim disk space.  If you have "innodb_file_per_table" in my.cnf, you can have separate ibd file per table which you can reclaim IF you drop it, but the performance is slightly decreased.  String comparison stops when the first character mis-match. If you can predict which field is the most likely changed field, put it on the left to make the check faster. As I write early, I use perl but just PHP should work the same and better in command line mode or direct execute via cron.

Comment: We use innoDB only for the tables used by the cron and the webshop front. All other tables in the CRM still are MyISAM as it was set as default.

Comment: If  you use the database approach, i.e. load all records to MySQL (InnoDB), do the check against "all other tables" (MyISAM), and delete (or drop) the table; Please have a look at my.cnf and the file size of ibdata1 under MYSQL's datadir.  InnoDB supports row level locking, which solves the locking problem. But the disk space reclaim will eventually be another problem.

Comment: Our server admin will be happy to hear he was right about innoDB :)